# Recent review on high density equation of state?

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, density-of-states

Can anyone suggest a recent review on the equation of state of the matter at high (nuclear and above) densities?

I would like this review to contain both astrophysical applications, mainly for neutron stars, and nuclear applications.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found what I was looking for by myself. I post this answer in case someone somewhere might need it.

The paper is *Gravitational waves from neutron star mergers and their relation to the nuclear equation of state* by Luca Baiotti Progr. Part. Phys. And Nucl. Phys. **109** (2019) 103714